# Типы базы данных - что общего

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite, oracle

При проектировании базы данных (таблиц) можно учесть ее использование в разных СУБД

(mysql, postgresql, mssql, sqlite, oracle)

Хочу чтобы была возможность выбирать базу данных и не было бы проблем в типах и таблицах

Такое возможно?

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите, чтобы в вашей системе можно было выбирать СУБД и (почти) не иметь при этом проблем, необходимо ввести некоторую "прослойку" между базой и логикой вашего приложения. Для этого можно использовать технологию **[Object-relational mapping](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM)**

Существует множество библиотек для разных языков программирования и с поддержкой различных СУБД.

Для платформы `.NET`:

- `Entity Framework` - поддерживает MSSQL, MySQL, ORACLE, PostgreSQL, Firebird и другие
- `NHibernate`  - поддерживает MSSQL, MySQL, ORACLE, PostgreSQL, Firebird, Sqlite и другие
- `Telerik OpenAccess` - поддерживает MSSQL, MySQL, ORACLE, PostgreSQL
- и много других

Для `PHP`

- `Doctrine` - очень обширная и функциональная библиотека, поддерживает много разных СУБД через свой собственный слой абстракции
- и много других

Для `Javascript (node.js)` есть модуль `node-orm` с поддержкой нескольких популярных реляционных СУБД. [И так далее...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)

Answer (score 1):

Настоятельно советую автору разрабатывать несколько версий под каждую субд отдельно.

Это если действительно хотите написать качественный продукт под несколько субд.

Answer (score 0):

В каждой из этих баз как минимум отличается реализация автонумерация значений в колонках (autoincrement). Будет сложно. :-)

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите сделать, не так просто... mysql, postgresql, mssql, sqllite, oracle отличаются друг от друга, семантика кода разная, и как следствие проблемы будут с типами данных и автоинкрементом полей. Думаю не заморачиваться на этом и определиться с СУБД, выбрать ту, которая больше всего вас устраивает...